# Please kindly spare one second to help me check the use of Fubini in this stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I am facing a problem in stochastic control and wonder if my method is right. I will try to simplify my situation.
First I have this GBM:

$dY_t = \mu_Y Y_t dt+ \sigma_Y Y_t dB_1(t)$ And obviously $Y_t=Y_0 \exp\left[ \mu_Y t - \frac{\sigma_Y^2}{2} t +\sigma_Y B_1(t) \right]$

Using the Clark-Ocone Representation Theorem:

$Y_t=Y_0 \exp\left( \mu_Y t \right) + \sigma_Y  \int_{0}^{t} Y_t dB(t)$

The state variable evloves like

$dX_t = rX_t dt + Y_t dt$

Here, I try to use Fubini's Theorem:

$\begin{aligned}
dX_t &= rX_t dt + Y_0 \exp\left( \mu_Y t \right) dt + \sigma_Y  \int_{0}^{t} Y_t dB(t) dt \\
& = rX_t dt + Y_0 \exp\left( \mu_Y t \right) dt + \sigma_Y  \int_{0}^{t} Y_t dt dB(t)
\end{aligned}$

In this way, I am able to proceed the task I face. So, I am wondering if the Fubini use is correct, please help me check it. Many thanks!

Comment: Stochastic integrals are not integrals w.r.t measures. Fubini is not applicable, unless there is a version of the theorem that I am not aware of.

Comment: @geetha290krm
Many thanks for your comment! I will look for some literature to further check this.  By the way, my main goal is to reveal the brownian motion in the evolution equation of $dX_t$. Do you have any good ideas?